# Calculating the area of a region using a mapping

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

The region: $\{{(x,y) \mid x^{2} < y < 2x^{2}, 2y^{2}<x<3y^{2}, x > 0, y > 0}\}$

The mapping: $u = y/x^{2}$,  $v = x/y^{2}$

I calculated the jacobian to be $\frac 34$ which means that the area of the original region is $3/4$ the area of the mapped region. Now I need to find the area of the mapped region.

How? I don't know what to put in terms of what and am completely lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapped region is a rectangular region that is defined by the equations:

For $y = x^2, u = 1$, $y = 2x^2, u = 2$.
For $x = 2y^2, v = 2$, and $x = 3y^2, v = 3$. You can sketch the mapped region in $uv$-coordinates.

Comment: So those are the bounds of integration, do I just us u*v as the integrand?

Comment: Yes, they are, and the area is $1$. So the answer is $3/4$.